# VS Code shows modified file

Tags: vs-code, git

We are working on two types of OS - Windows and Mac.
I'm just retrieving code from org and VS Code shows that it is modified, but it doesn't.
How to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if you're using a git repository, especially when dealing with Windows vs. Linux/Mac, you'll find that these changes can happen. This is typically due to line ending differences in Linux and Windows. Linux uses a simple LF (Line Feed) character, while Windows, being a descendent of MS-DOS, uses a CR LF (Carriage Return, Line Feed) tuple. These differences can cause a ton of apparently "blank" diffs to occur in all the files. The typical way to handle this is through [Git settings](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), specifically core.autocrlf=true.

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

This will convert CRLF to LF on commit, making sure the files are binary-exact for all developers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Salesforce every time we retrieve code from org returns endline changes.
Command "git config core.fileMode false" solved this issue